# UWP . How to prevent app from closing on error?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an app that give the user the possibility to pick a file, from the pc/mobile. If the file is corrupt or is not well formatted the app crashes and close itself!!
Since that file become the default one, the user have to uninstall and reinstall the app so everything get the original setup.

This is an example, the real question is how to prevent any app from closing in any type of error!?

Comment: Have you heard of `try {} catch () {}`?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be seeking to avoid closing for every type of error. Take the errors that you know of and can do something *specifically* to deal with, and let the others continue to kill the app. By definition, the others are the ones where you didn't correctly anticipate what situation you've ended up in and for all you know, the app continuing to run may cause *more* damage in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those cases exceptions are most likely being thrown. When an exception is thrown, it has the opportunity to be caught using `try` and `catch`.

```
try
{
     //Do something
}
catch
{
     //Something went wrong.
}
```

It's up to the developer to decide what to do when faced with an exception. Ignoring it (leaving the catch block) is usually a bad idea. Instead, you may want to do something like show a message to the user and ask them to pick a different photo.

> how to prevent any app from closing in any type of error!?

Apps usually cannot do this. What should the application do when it is faced with an error, and the rest of the code cannot work when that error happens?

It's up to you to decide how an error should be handled, and how to safely continue. Putting your entire application in a try/catch doesn't work as the app will not be able to do anything meaningful from then on out.

If there is an area of your application that needs error handling, then add it. Sometimes there is no good way to continue running a program, and closing it is the best option.

Comment: I know the try/catch, I was looking for "some any other way" for any kind of errors that we are not expecting. Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use try/catch:

```
try { 
          stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
          Frame.Navigate(typeof(music)); // optional to back to choose page 
    }
```

Then you can check what causes the exception and what type is it. You may prompt user to do sth again or show what is wrong with file.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful, but the other answer was more complete in my way of seeing ;-)